# Asymptotic behavior of the sum $\sum_{k\le x}\frac{1}{\varphi(k)}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Suppose $x>0$ and let $f(x)=\sum_{k\le x}\frac{1}{\varphi(k)}$, where $\varphi(k)$ is the Euler totient function. It is well known that $\sum_{k\le x}\frac{1}{k}\sim\log x$. What is the asymptotic behavior of the sum $f(x)=\sum_{k\le x}\frac{1}{\varphi(k)}$?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a question that addresses the mentioned asymptotics - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683190/showing-sum-n-leq-x-frac1-phi-n-c-log-x-o1?noredirect=1&lq=1
Roughly, you can proceed by the standard convolution method via approximating $1/\varphi(n)$ as $1/n$.